# MySQL compile libs

Tags: mysql, qt, dll

I am having real problem with compiling MySQL libraries for Qt in Windows and Mac. Essentially, I cannot use mysql with a Qt application because of missing the file QMYSQL. I am pretty much new when it comes to configure and install applications in Unix-like systems. However, building libraries for Qt looks like this. I have read a little bit about GNU C and GNU Make to understand what is done but it is still overwhelming me.

The guide in Qt Project says I should have folder include and lib/opt in which I should have libmysql.lib file. There's no such folder like opt/ but there is the file libmysql.lib and libmysql.dll in /lib folder. Qt Project website does not say that but I have copied everything to C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/plugins/sqldriver/mysql where I also found mysql.pro. I run this command:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATHS+=include" "LIB+=libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
```

and the program generated a Makefile for me. When I run "make", or "make release" etc. make stops always at the same point and states there is no "mysql.lib" file. I cannot find this file anywhere.

Does anybody has any idea how to do it? Please, at least direct me where I could start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has worked for me: Unfortunately, I had to install the whole Qt(v 4.8.2) from sources. I strongly recommend it. It has a huge impact on your experience, although it may sometimes be a real pain.

I have:

- installed the latest MinGW 4.7.0 using self-intaller + additional tools
- installed the latest MySQL Database engine + Connector/C via intaller MSI (ZIP archive did not worked) in a folder without spaces in its name (C:\Mysql-libs\ etc.)
- built makefile by calling configure with following parameters:

  > configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -platform win32-g++-4.6 -plugin-sql-mysql -I C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\include -L C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\lib -L C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\lib\opt -plugin-sql-odbc -developer-build -no-qt3support -openssl -I C:\openssl\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L C:\openssl\OpenSSL-Win32
- and finally

  mingw32-make.exe

Special attention should be on
`-platform win32-g++4.6`
if MinGW 4.6.x+ is used. It did not seem to work when I used
`-platform win32-g++` etc. I hope it will help the others to build MySql libraries for Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download and install the MySQL Connector (which includes the required lib)? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ These are the requirements you seem to be missing.

Make sure to install those and then set up the paths to the various required files. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. I tried to download a connector but it did not help. It is still the same problem. Is there any document where I could find out how to correctly build static or dynamic libraries?

Comment: It did not help how? You should now have the required libraries on your system. Do you or don't you?

Comment: No, it didn't. It is for sure that I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out--just lack of experience I am afraid.I am not sure if you have time and a desire to track what I have done but if you do so, I have made two more threads in two different forums where I tried to explain in details what I did and what I was supposed to obtain. As I said, this is first time I am trying to do

Comment: Additionally, In connector/C, I've found: bin/mysql_config.exe, includes, and three other files in lib/: libmysql.dll, libmysql.lib, and mysqlclient.lib. Also, there is no lib/opt folder which supposed to be there according to Qt Documentation.

It is for sure something I am doing wrong but I cannot figure it out--just lack of experience I suppose. I am not sure if you have time and a desire to track what I have done but if you do so, I would be grateful if you see my thread in Qt Center:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50581-Huge-problems-while-installing-QMYSQL-driver?p=227163#post227163

Comment: I just installed it (6.0.2) and for me there is a lib/opt folder. This does contain libmysql.dll, libmysql.lib and some other libs as well. If that is the lib dir for you, that should be fine. Just remove the `opt` from your path then. Try changing your linker parameters to link against libmysql.lib rather than mysql.lib which you seem to be doing now according to the error message (though your question seems to state so properly).

Comment: Hi. Before, I downloaded zip archives which did not have aforementioned folder opt. I was surprised when you've mentioned you've found it. I have installed connector from an installed and the opt folder is there.

I cannot understand that there is the difference in files when installed via zip or windows installer. I will be trying to compile the driver now. Hope it will go now. Just a question. If mysql is 64bit I should install connectors for 64bit, am I right? Thanks

Comment: If you compile everything in 64 bit, then yes. Just keep that consistent.

Comment: Thanks. I mean mysql is 64bit, but qt application might be 32.

Anyway, it's not working. Just to make sure, I copied everything from mysql Connector to C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql" to keep path shorter and run qmake:

qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\ApacheMySqlPhp\MySql\include" "LIBS+=C:\ApacheMySqlPhp\MySql\lib\opt\libmysql.lib" -o Makefile mysql.pro

Then, "make release" and I got bunch of error that I cannot even copied here. So I decided to put them in txt file and they are availabel from this address:
http://zebik.republika.pl/log_from_make.txt

I don't know why linker cannot link those functions.

Comment: No no no. Never ever mix 64bit libraries with 32bit applications. If your application is 32bit, your libraries should be 32 bit. Mixing the two will never work and might well be the cause of the linker errors.

Comment: I though it could be the conflict if I connect to the server via 32 bit libraries because the server is 64 bit. I thought it should be other way round. Thanks

Comment: It passed through yesterday. I don't know why. I did use 32 bit libraries before and it could not work. Qt still does not recognize those libraries so I suspect I probably need to build the whole Qt from sources and implement mysql using configure. At this stage, I just like to thank for your help and effort :)

Comment: No problem at all. Just a heads up, should your problem be resolved, then you can accept the answer that helped you most. This is not a requirement and nobody can ever force you to accept something. It just indicates that your problem is resolved and what helped you most for other users/visitor. Have a look at this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to install the whole Qt(v 4.8.2) from sources
I have installed the latest:
- MinGW 4.7.0
- MySQL 5.5.27 + Connector/C via installer MSI (ZIP did not worked) into `C:\Mysql-libs` no spaces in name etc.
I've configured all:

`configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -platform win32-g++-4.6 -plugin-sql-mysql -I C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\include -L C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\lib -L C:\ApacheMysqlPhp\Mysql\lib\opt -plugin-sql-odbc -developer-build -no-qt3support -openssl -I C:\openssl\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L C:\openssl\OpenSSL-Win32`

and finally built libs

`mingw32-make`

Comment: And that worked? (If so, perhaps create your own answer. Who knows, it might be valuable to others. You can even accept your own answer then)

Comment: Spacial attention should be on

`-platform win32-g++4.6`

if MinGW 4.6.x+ is used. It did not seem to work when I used
`-platform win32-g++` etc. I hope it will help the others to build MySql libraries for Qt.

Comment: Make that an answer. Don't hide valuable info within comments. You are really encouraged to do so.

Comment: @ZikO You really don't need to accept my answer if that did not solve your problem. I would much rather see that you add an answer of your own, detailing how you managed to solve it. That would be far more useful. But it's up to you.

Comment: I just don't know how to make my own answer the answer. Sorry

Comment: Just as you would add any answer. No difference.

Comment: It's a bit confusing but I finally found it